# GetSherlockActivity not found

Tags: java, android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to use this code for sending a message through whatsapp. The problem I have is, that "The method getSherlockActivity() is undefined for the type Send". Should I rename my Send or do I need to import something? The only suggestion eclipse makes, is creating it.

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Send extends SherlockActivity{

    public void sendWhatsAppMessageTo(String whatsappid) {

        Cursor c = getSherlockActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.Data._ID }, ContactsContract.Data.DATA1 + "=?",
                new String[] { whatsappid }, null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        Intent whatsapp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/" + c.getString(0)));
        c.close();

         if (whatsapp != null) {

        startActivity(whatsapp);      

        } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
        //download for example after dialog
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.whatsapp");
                        Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            }

        }

}
```

EDIT: Logcat output after removing the getSherlockActivity() is:

```
02-15 02:05:10.647: D/AndroidRuntime(2831): Shutting down VM
02-15 02:05:10.647: W/dalvikvm(2831): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a151f8)
02-15 02:05:10.647: E/AndroidRuntime(2831): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-15 02:05:10.647: E/AndroidRuntime(2831): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.wiers.whatsapp_api/de.wiers.whatsapp_api.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-15 02:05:10.647: E/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
02-15 02:05:10.647: E/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
02-15 02:05:10.647: E/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-15 02:05:10.647: E/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
02-15 02:05:10.647: E/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-15 02:05:10.647: E/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-15 02:05:10.647: E/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-15 02:05:10.647: E/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-15 02:05:10.647: E/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-15 02:05:10.647: E/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-15 02:05:10.647: E/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-15 02:05:10.647: E/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-15 02:05:10.647: E/AndroidRuntime(2831): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-15 02:05:10.647: E/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:91)
02-15 02:05:10.647: E/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at de.wiers.whatsapp_api.Send.sendWhatsAppMessageTo(Send.java:15)
02-15 02:05:10.647: E/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at de.wiers.whatsapp_api.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
02-15 02:05:10.647: E/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4492)
02-15 02:05:10.647: E/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-15 02:05:10.647: E/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
02-15 02:05:10.647: E/AndroidRuntime(2831):     ... 11 more
02-15 02:05:11.527: I/dalvikvm(2831): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-15 02:05:11.537: I/dalvikvm(2831): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-15 02:05:11.547: I/dalvikvm(2831): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-15 02:05:11.547: I/dalvikvm(2831): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

EDIT2: Main File:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import de.wiers.whatsapp_api.Send;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Send snd = new Send();
        snd.sendWhatsAppMessageTo("12345678@s.whatsapp.net");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



}
```

Comment: I think your Eclipse is red anyway ... Make sure you're referencing correctly the Sherlock library.

Comment: @gunar: I have imported it, that's the only error I get. Also the import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity; works

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20297451/3134811), you can change `getSherlockActivity` to `this`.

Comment: I already tried that, I get Unable to Start ComponentInfo Null Pointer Exception in Runtime.

Comment: Then again, here is another  [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19044104/3134811)

Comment: Still getting "unable to Start Activity ComponentInfo: Null Pointer Exception" in Runtime

Comment: You need to check if your c null with this. That's all i can say.
if(cursor != null){cursor.moveToFirst(); }  Also it would be helpful if you post logcat output.

Comment: I have added Logcat output now.

Comment: can you post your MainActivity too, or just 15. line
(`at de.wiers.whatsapp_api.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)`)

Comment: I have added main now

Comment: I'm not sure do you have more imports at the top so i have to ask which is line 15 on Send class?

Comment: Line 15 is the one starting with snd.sendWhatsAppMessageTo(

Comment: In Send class, not in MainActivity.

Comment: It's this one `Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,`

Comment: I researched a bit, i don't think i'm able to help you at this. I suggest you to wait for someone to help, while waiting look at the articles like [this](http://android-codelabs.appspot.com/resources/tutorials/contactsprovider/ex2.html). Your problem is not with GetSherlockActivity i think. Oh and are you using emulator for testing?

Comment: I am not using emulator, I am using a real android tablet running Android 4.0.4